# Replace date outliers with mean for a week

Tags: r

I'm trying to run some statistics on air quality data but the sensors have a couple of days with errors: where the sensor was either offline, or readings were too high. I'd like to replace the data on those days with the average for the week for that location (sensor).

```
airDataWork <- data.frame(
    Location= c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
    Date = 2021-03-19, 2021-03-20, 2021-03-21, 2021-03-22, 2021-03-19, 2021-03-20, 2021-03-21),
    maxParticulates=c(10,0,12,1900,2,2,1000)
)

#set bounds
lower_bound <- quantile(airDataWork$maxParticulates, 0.10)
upper_bound <- quantile(airDataWork$maxParticulates, 0.90)

#get the outliers
outlier_ind <- which(airDataWork$maxParticulates < lower_bound | airDataWork$maxParticulates > upper_bound)

#exclude the outliers and store the average for each location\week
airDataClean <- airDataWork[-outlier_ind, ] %>% 
   group_by(Location, year(Date), week(Date)) %>%
   summarise(mean(maxParticulates))

#????
```

How can I now update the maxParticulates figure in my outlier data with average figure from airDataClean for the Location/year/week using Location/Date in the source?

Edit:

[Solution slightly modified from that suggested by @JKupzig - with thanks]

```
airDataWork %<>% mutate( 
   Year=lubridate::year(Date), 
   Week=lubridate::week(Date) 
) 

airDataClean <- airDataWork %>% 
  group_by(Location, Year, Week) %>% 
  summarise(newVal=mean(maxParticulates)) %>% 
  right_join(
    airDataWork, ., 
    by=c("Location"="Location", 'Year'='Year', 'Week'='Week')
  ) %>% 
  mutate( 
    maxParticulates = ifelse(
     (
       (maxParticulates <= lower_bound) | 
       (maxParticulates >= upper_bound)
     ), 
     newVal, maxParticulates)
   ) %>% 
  select(., c(1,2,3)) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **base R**

We may exploit `split` to split the `airDataWork` by `Location`. Then use `lapply` to get the mean `maxParticulates` per `Location` in case the value of `maxParticulates` is an classified as an outlier (according to your definition). If it is not an outlier, keep the original value of `maxParticulates`.

```
# your definition of the outliers
lower_bound <- quantile(airDataWork$maxParticulates, 0.10)
upper_bound <- quantile(airDataWork$maxParticulates, 0.90)

# create the desired output values
maxParticulates_update <-
  do.call(c,lapply(split(airDataWork, airDataWork$Location), \(x) {
    with(x, ifelse(maxParticulates < lower_bound | maxParticulates > upper_bound,
                   mean(maxParticulates), maxParticulates))
  }))

# copy your original data.frame
airDataClean <- airDataWork

# assign the desired output values to this new data.frame
airDataClean$maxParticulates <- unname(maxParticulates_update)
```

**Output**

```
> airDataClean
  Location       Date maxParticulates
1        a 2021-03-19            10.0
2        a 2021-03-20           480.5
3        a 2021-03-21            12.0
4        a 2021-03-22           480.5
5        b 2021-03-19             2.0
6        b 2021-03-20             2.0
7        b 2021-03-21          1000.0
```

**Data**

```
airDataWork <- structure(list(Location = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"
), Date = structure(c(18705, 18706, 18707, 18708, 18705, 18706, 
18707), class = "Date"), maxParticulates = c(10, 0, 12, 1900, 
2, 2, 1000)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using dplyr**

A dplyr solution could be to summarize the grouped values (as you were are doing) and then using a join-function and a simple ifelse condition to change the outliers:

```
airDataWork %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  group_by(Location, lubridate::year(Date), lubridate::week(Date)) %>%
  summarise(newVal=mean(maxParticulates)) %>% 
  right_join(airDataWork, .) %>%
  mutate(maxParticulates = ifelse(((maxParticulates <= lower_bound) | (maxParticulates >= upper_bound)), newVal, maxParticulates)) %>%
  select(., c(1,2,3)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

  Location       Date maxParticulates
1        a 2021-03-19            10.0
2        a 2021-03-20           480.5
3        a 2021-03-21            12.0
4        a 2021-03-22           480.5
5        b 2021-03-19             2.0
6        b 2021-03-20             2.0
7        b 2021-03-21          1000.0
```

**Used Data**

```
airDataWork <- data.frame(
  Location= c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
  Date = c("2021-03-19", "2021-03-20", "2021-03-21", "2021-03-22", "2021-03-19", "2021-03-20", "2021-03-21"),
maxParticulates=c(10,0,12,1900,2,2,1000))

lower_bound <- quantile(airDataWork$maxParticulates, 0.10)
upper_bound <- quantile(airDataWork$maxParticulates, 0.90)
```

Comment: I got duplicates from the join. Mod'd to:
```
airDataWork %<>% mutate(
   Year=lubridate::year(Date), Week=lubridate::week(Date)
)
airDataClean <- airDataWork %>%
  group_by(Location, Year, Week) %>%
  summarise(newVal=mean(maxParticulates)) %>%
  right_join(airDataWork, ., by=c("Location"="Location", 'Year'='Year', 'Week'='Week'))  %>%
  mutate(
     maxParticulates = ifelse(((maxParticulates <= lower_bound) | (maxParticulates >= upper_bound)), 
                           newVal, maxParticulates)) %>%
   select(., c(1,2,3)) %>% 
   as.data.frame() ```
Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by duplicates. I've added the used data, so you can see if there might be any differences from your data that causes the duplicates. @PaulSmith

Comment: Duplicates were after the join statement. Somehow the right join (in my environment at leas) was creating a line for each row in each side.